# The TCP/IP connection to the host SQLServer, port 1433 has failed for CDC target DB with JDBC sink connector

Tags: sql-server, docker, jdbc, apache-kafka-connect, cdc

I am trying to do CDC from Postgres to SQL Server 2019.I installed Postgres in Ubuntu(WSL).I am running SQL Server 2019 in docker inside WSL ubuntu. I have used below command

```
sudo docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=<password>" \
   -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 --hostname sql1 \
   -d \
   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

I am able to login inside SQL server with user `/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P <password>` and able to execute db commands.and created TestDB.

I have started zookeeper,kafka and kafka connect in same server.
Postgres and SQL server both are running in same server.
I have kept all the respective jars inside kafka connect plugin.
I am able to create source connector and target connector.
For target connector below is the config

```
{
    "name": "jdbc-sink-sql",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "customers",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://sql1:1433;databaseName=TestDB",
        "connection.user": "sa",
        "connection.password": "<password>",
        "transforms": "unwrap",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones":"false",
        "auto.create": "true",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "delete.enabled":"true",
        "pk.fields": "id",
        "pk.mode": "record_key"        
    }
}'
```

Once the target connector is created I am seeing below error in kafka connect log

```
[2023-03-28 22:53:32,951] INFO [jdbc-sink-sql|task-0] Unable to connect to database on attempt 1/3. Will retry in 10000 ms. (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider:87)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host sql1, port 1433 has failed. Error: "sql1. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:237)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.convertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:288)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2574)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:715)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3427)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:3077)
```

I am not able to understand what needs to be done.
I have searched net and found what is to be done incase SQL server is running in windows.
But did not find while running in docker container what else to be done.while running the image I have already opened 1433 port.
I need some guidance on how to fix this error.

Comment: The `default` bridge network in Docker doesn't have DNS resolution available for container names so it probably isn't resolving `sql1`. Have you tried running all of the SQL and Kafka containers from a single `docker-compose.yml` composition instead? (This will create a DNS-enabled network and allow the containers to resolve one another by name.)

Comment: No I haven't tried in a single docker-compose. I ran only sql server in docker. When I have tried CDC for sql server(source) to postgres(target) using debezium it worked and did not give any issue while reading the db but incase sql server is used as target with jdbc sink connector.it is giving this issue.

Comment: Since Debezium is running directly on the Docker host (i.e.: **not** in a container), and since you have published `sql1`'s container port to host port 1433, have you tried `jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=TestDB` yet?

Comment: I tried to do "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=TestDB" then I received error like "The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "PKIX path building failed: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". Then I searched this error in net and modified the connection string like "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=TestDB;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true". Then it started working.Now it is writing all the events to sqlserver table.Thanks @AlwaysLearning

Answer (score 0):

Unclear where you are running Connect, but assuming not in a container, then your string needs to use `127.0.0.1` in place of `sql1` since your host has no DNS resolution to Docker container names (and you never used `--name sql1` in your Docker command).

As you put in the comments,

```
jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=TestDB;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true
```

**However** - I would strongly recommend not installing Kafka Connect and SQL Server on the same machine. Kafka Connect is best ran as a cluster (multiple machines). If you submit a task with `127.0.0.1`, then have multiple Connect servers, then they all will try to communicate with a database server on their individual machines rather than a central, common database. Therefore, you should instead use your FQDN / LAN IP as the address, instead.

Comment: I was doing POC.So I took same machine.I was running SQL server only in container in that m/c. Kafka and postgres I have installed there

Comment: Sounds good. If this post address your question, feel free to accept the answer using the checkmark next to the post